# Does TensorFlow Serving allows plugins (dynamically linked user extensions)?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I wish to have an ability to write a dynamic plugin (*.so) which will allow the server to use data from the Amazon queue. Working data to make predictions based on an already taught model.

I have read the manual about the server extension points
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/architecture.md

It says it is allowed to have custom sources, including the cloud ones. The problems are, I was unable to find a good complete example for the beginners (like I am), the help is a tiny one, and (if I understand correctly), those custom modules should be **statically** linked in the server code (which is, for some serious reasons uncontrollable by me, is not acceptable).